# Update a mongodb and return what has exactly has changed?

Tags: mongodb, go

So i have a program constantly running watching an API endpoint. When something on the endpoint has changed, it updates the mongodb document exactly how I want it. Next, I want to be able to get what has changed in the document, and lets just say use that has a variable or whatever i decide to do with it. Right now, I can get it to update and just tell me that the document has been changed, but not get what EXACTLY has changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are replacing the document, you cannot get what was changed, but you can get the version of the document before the change was applied, so you can figure out the differences. In the official mongodb driver, use the `FindOneAndReplace` function to get the document as it was before the update, and then compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

1. read mongo log, or
2. write a code to compare between original data and updated data, or
3. you can add 1 more field which is updated to data

If you want more detailed version, I suggest you use mongo log [mongoDB Profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/) section Update Operation.

Here is the snippet of the log:

```
{
   "op" : "update",
   "ns" : "test.report",
   "command" : {
      "q" : { },
      "u" : { "$rename" : { "a" : "b" } },
      "multi" : true,
      "upsert" : false
   },
   .............
```

Hope it helps.